# Cannot filter divs with two tab groups using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, navigation

I'm trying to filter divs based on two tab groups(navs), but I can't get it to work. I don't want the page to refresh because i will have a lot of content before this section. I know this would be more efficient with AJAX, but can it be done without it? I have filter divs before with just one tab group without using ajax, but i don't know if it's possible here because i'm using two tab groups. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').click(function(){
        var tabID = $(this).data('tabid'); 

        $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').children().removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('.mainContent').children().hide(); 
        $('.mainContent').find("[data-blockid="+tabID+"]").show();
    });

    $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').click(function(){
        var tabID = $(this).data('tabid'); 

        $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').children().removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('.mainContent').children().hide(); 
        $('.mainContent').find("[data-blockid="+tabID+"]").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.current{
    background: red;
} 
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
}
li:hover{
    background: red;
}
.mainNav ul{
    display: flex
}
.mainNav ul li{
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.collegeTypeNav{
    background: #c4d8ff;
}
.collegeTypeNav ul{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.collegeTypeNav ul li{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.middleContent{
    display: flex;
}
.aboutCollegeNav{
    background: #d1ffe4;
}
.aboutCollegeNav ul{
    padding: 0px;
}
.aboutCollegeNav ul li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}

.mainContent{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <nav class="mainNav">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="current">About Majors</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
   <section class="collegesIntro">
      <div>
         <h1>ABOUT MAJORS</h1>
         <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore
            magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
            commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
            est
            laborum. </p>
      </div>
   </section>

   <section class="collegesInformation">

      <nav class="collegeTypeNav">
         <ul>
            <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="engineering">Engineering</li>
            <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="science">Science</li>
            <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="liberalArts">Liberal Arts</li>
         </ul>
      </nav>

      <div class="middleContent">
      
         <nav class="aboutCollegeNav">
            <ul>
               <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="overview">Overview</li>
               <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="statistics">Statistics</li>
               <li role="button" class="tab" data-tabid="courses">Courses</li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         
         <div class="mainContent">
            <div data-blockid="engineering overview">
               <h3> engineering overview</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="engineering statistics">
               <h3> engineering statistics </h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="engineering courses">
               <h3> engineering courses</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="science overview">
               <h3>science overview </h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="science statistics">
               <h3> science statistics</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="science courses">
               <h3>science courses</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="liberalArts overview">
               <h3>liberalArts overview</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="liberalArts statistics">
               <h3>liberalArts statistics</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-blockid="liberalArts courses">
               <h3>liberalArts courses</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                  aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu
                  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Your javascript code with this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var collageID = $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
    var aboutID = $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').first().addClass('current').data('tabid');
    showDiv();

    $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').click(function(){
        $('.collegeTypeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
        collageID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
        showDiv();
    });


    $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').click(function(){
        $('.aboutCollegeNav .tab').removeClass('current');
        aboutID = $(this).addClass('current').data('tabid');
        showDiv();
    });

    function showDiv(){
        $('.mainContent > div').hide();
        if(collageID && aboutID){
            $('.mainContent').find('[data-blockid="'+collageID +' ' + aboutID + '"]').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you add the current class to each nav li? To show where you are.

Comment: Add the current class after clicking on the particular tab menu.

Comment: So I added  $(this).addClass('current'); to each tab menu, but then how do you remove it once another li is clicked on the same tab menu?

Comment: Thanks!! But what do you so you only see the first filtered results when the page first loads?

Comment: When page load the all the results are shown. after clicking on the first tab menu then  results is filtered based on that menu, and after clicking on the second tab menu then the result is filtered on both the tab menus

Comment: First of all, I am removing all the current classes from the child menus and then add the current class to the selected menu

Comment: Is there a way to only show the results from the first of each nav at first? So is it possible to just show the Engineering Overview Div at first?

Comment: Default tab case added

Comment: Is it possible to put the current li text of the collegeTypeNav at the top of the aboutColleNav as a h3 title?